# How do I add back elements with GWT after removing them with DOM.removeChild()?

Tags: dom, gwt, static, element

I am using GWT 2.5 for an application. I have some static HTML with a specially named div, and I am using `HTMLPanel.wrap()` to replace that div with a GWT login panel. Once the user logs in I am using `DOM.removeChild()` to remove all the static elements from the page and use nothing but GWT widgets. This all works great. The static HTML looks something like:

```
<body><div id="main_content"><div id="embed_content"></div></div></body>
```

However, after logging out, I would like to replace all the static elements I had previously removed and replace the special div with the login panel again so that it looks the same as when you first log in. I have tried many different ways to do this, but they usually fail with an error:

> "A widget that has an existing parent widget may not be added to the detach list"

when I try to wrap the div again. My code to wrap the div is:

```
  RootPanel rpe = RootPanel.get("embed_content");
  rpe.clear();
  Element child;
  while((child = DOM.getFirstChild(rpe.getElement())) != null) {
   DOM.removeChild(rpe.getElement(), child);
  }
  HTMLPanel.wrap(rpe.getElement()).add(this);
```

with "this" being an HTMLPanel. The code to remove the elements is:

```
  RootPanel rpm = RootPanel.get("main_content");
  rpm.clear();
  Element child;
  while((child = DOM.getFirstChild(rpm.getElement())) != null) {
   DOM.removeChild(rpm.getElement(), child);
  }
  HTMLPanel.wrap(rpm.getElement()).add(this);
```

The closest I have gotten is to save the elements in an array, and then when when I want to display the static content again, I use `DOM.appendChild()` to add them back. At that point the "embed_content" element exist and everything is happy except I get the error mentioned above on the `HTMLPanel.wrap` statement. So I don't know if I am using the wrong approach, or what. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I guess I need to stop answering my own questions. On this one, it looks like I was horribly wrong to even attempt it. It all worked in development mode but not production mode, so I had to completely rethink how to do what I wanted. The two main issues (it turns out) was using RootPanel.get().add() and manipulating the static HTML. Long story short, here is an example from the initial "please wait" screen of what I ended up going with:

```
Element child;
RootPanel rpm = RootPanel.get("main_content");
String html = rpm.getElement().getInnerHTML();
rpm.clear();
while((child = DOM.getFirstChild(rpm.getElement())) != null) {
  DOM.removeChild(rpm.getElement(), child);
}

HTMLPanel panel = new HTMLPanel(html);
String msg = "<h2>Please Wait</h2><p>Please wait a moment for " +
  "the application to load.</p>";
panel.addAndReplaceElement(new HTML(msg), "embed_content");
this.add(panel);
this.setWidth("100%");
RootLayoutPanel.get().add(new ScrollPanel(this));
```

So in other instances I need to read the file on the server, and send the HTML via RPC.